# Understanding embed links

Tags: html, web, cross-domain, embed

In HTML we have  tag to make an embed for your page in other pages, but I was wondering for how when you share a Youtube link on whatsapp or Spotify song link on telegram, you get a small player  like you embedded that site in the message.

- How is that possible?
- How can I implement this feature into my site.

I searched google and MDN for this but no result.

Comment: Look at the source code of the web page.

Comment: bro, I searched iframes and embeds a lot and looked at the web page code. but for some reasons when I read your comment I remembred there is the <head> and it looks it is the og properties in meta (open graph), but still cant understand how it was used to be played in that site, like youtube videos have small player with only the video and not the whole page.